# getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream is returning null

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to access Admin.proprties in Ejb project insideAdmin.ear
When i debug i see is variable InputStream variable IS  is null below is code i am using to load property file

```
 InputStream is = PropertiesLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Admin.properties");
```

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure
    xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
        
              <module name="com.Test" />  
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I have created  folder in wildfly/module like com/test/main

inside main folder copied Admin.properties  and created module.xml
my module.xml.I am new to wildfly. Can anyone guide me the way to load external property files from wildfly in ejb project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.Test">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="."/>  
    </resources>  
</module>
```